# History behind Mahishasura Mardini Stotram?

Tags: history, devi, stotra

I was listening to this powerful stotram on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=442ewPgXHQ0).
Don't know why but there were tears in my eyes it's so powerful!

For knowledge sake just wanted to know some facts about it for instance:

- Who wrote it and when?
- What was the prime reason behind writing this stotram?
- Any other important known facts worth sharing.

Comment: It is a beautiful stotra. Whenever I listen this also got in tears. According to [greenmesg website](http://www.greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/mahishasura_mardini_stotram.php) it is created by Ramakrishna kavi or Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: Yes Many say it is by Adi Shankaracharya And RamaKrishna who was greatest devotee of Devi. This stotra encompasses almoat all great glories of Devi and Her form and Beauty. It is extremely poetic containing Onomatopoeia , Oxym Metaphor, Alliteration ..... It feels like getting intoxicated with the nectar falling from the strings of lotus like words of this stotra.

Comment: As per stories i know, Tenali Ramakrishna wrote it. He was born dull witted but got intellect after praying to Goddess Kali and then he wrote Mahishasura Mardini Stotram for Goddess.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Tenali Ramakrishna as in Tenali Raman right? with King Krishnadevaraya ?

Comment: @ABcDexter Yes. Tenali Ramakrishna of Krishnadevaraya .

Comment: Okay. Then let me research this topic well, I should be able to find the original source of the Stotram :D